# Better to go first in Snakes and Ladders?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

We consider the game as described in http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/november12011/ . Each person rolls a dice and the person who gets 6 on the face can start and the other keeps waiting. If the completion of your move results in your token landing at the foot of a ladder, you instantly climb to the top of that ladder. Correspondingly, if your move lands you on the head of a snake, you are forced to slide down the snake to an earlier square. There are no consequences to landing on the top of a ladder or the tail of a snake. The change compared to that in the link above is that if the person reaches the same spot as where the other person is at already, the person who was at that position earlier gets out and has to restart the game (again waiting for a 6 face). Thus, the plays of the two players become dependent.

With this variant, what is the probability for the person starting first to win?

One approach is to write the complete Markov transition probability but it will have joint state of players making it $100^2$ states which is not straightforward analytically (can be potentially done by computer in which $10^4\times 10^4$ matrix can be handled). Is there any other approach?

Comment: Just curious: in BrE we call this game "snakes and ladders" for reasons which are obvious reading your description. I'm aware that "chutes and ladders" is more common in AmE, but always assumed this corresponded with an absence of legless reptiles. Are there snakes, and if so why does the title refer to chutes?

Comment: It will be better to go first as the two players do not influence each other - each follows a random path through the same game which has a fixed, finite (but hard to calculate) expected length. The exact probability of player 1 winning will depend on the exact layout of the board but will be 0.5 + a small positive value.

Comment: Apologies, my assumption was incorrect, i missed the part where the players become dependent by interacting if they land on the same space.

Comment: An obvious other approach is the Monte Carlo simulation described in your link

Comment: The article you link to points out one optimization, that instead of some $101$ states for an individual player (counting the not yet on the board state), there are essentially only $82$ because a player cannot rest either at the head of a snake nor at the foot of a ladder.  Also I do not find the "waiting for a 6 face" rule occasioned by the linked article.  Does the off-board player, having rolled a six, roll again to find their move or must the player apply that six as their first move.  The latter interpretation would also slightly reduce the possible number of states.

Comment: It is the first. 6 is only to start, and the move amount is determined by rolling again.